# Counting the winning team getting "null" back when another name is expected?

Tags: java, null

Am not sure if I have missed something here. There are two teams, I am suppose to get back "Blue Jays" but I just keep getting null in my JUnit. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Thank you

```
public String winner(String team1, String team2) {

String winner = null;

for(Game g: games) {

    if ((g.getTeamOneName().equals(team1) && g.getTeamTwoName().equals(team2))
            || g.getTeamOneName().equals(team2) && g.getTeamTwoName().equals(team1)) {

        if (g.getTeamOneScore() > g.getTeamTwoScore()) {
            winner = g.getTeamOneName();
        }
        else if (g.getTeamOneScore() < g.getTeamTwoScore()) {
            winner = g.getTeamTwoName();
        }
        else if (g.getTeamOneScore() == g.getTeamTwoScore()) {
            winner = "tie";
        }
        else {
            winner = null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Also how many winners can you have.  The value of winner will change for every iteration of the loop

Comment: @ScaryWombat sorry I don't understand. Could you explain more. Thank you

Comment: @ScaryWombat how would I stop if from changing and just stop it when its found. I know of break but that's usually frowned upon.

Comment: `break` is not usually frowned upon at all.  If that is what you need then do it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat break didn't fix it : /

Comment: I suggest that you `debug` you code.  This could be as simple as printing out `g` at the top of your loop - show us this output and then we may be able to help you.

Comment: @ScaryWombat debugged and it was just skipped straight down to null and not looping. I removed the first if-statement and now it's giving me a different team than expect but it's not "null", so making progress.

Comment: BTW, as your are not even returning a `value` from this method, I am also guessing that this code ir not the code that you are running.

Comment: @ScaryWombat also changed it to just if's not else-if's

Answer (score -2):

You must return a String type at the end of the method.

So try to replace

`else{ winner=null; }`

with

`return winner;`